# Compare or align 3D objects

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, 3d, image-recognition

I have two 3D matrices. Each pixel is a gray scale value.

The first 3D matrix is a reference shape. e.g. imagine a 3D model of a mouth.

The second 3D matrix is an approximate subsection of the reference shape. e.g. imagine a tooth. The subsection is approximate as it is from a different mouth. Note the subsection could be slightly oblique.

The challenge is to identify what are the coordinates of the subsection inside the reference matrix. Expanding on the mouth example above, the challenge is to identify what tooth the second 3D matrix most accurately represents.

The output could be a 3D pixel location and an orientation value.

Comment: This is appropriate for the DataScience Stack Exchange (not StackOverflow)

Comment: thanks @Pete, I will repost there

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `imregister`, `imregtform` and `imwarp` to automatically align two volumetric datasets. See [matlab's documentation for an example...](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-multimodal-3-d-medical-images.html) 
Or if you want to work harder, convolve in 6D (`convn`) where you start with (x,y,z,theta=0,phi=0,psi=0) for the first matrix, and create a representation of the 3d tooth in all angle projections....

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @bla will take a look. Ideally, looking for a solution in python

Comment: @david_adler If you're looking for a solution in Python, don't tag the question with Matlab...

Comment: Ideally python, matlab is okay. I think I will have more support from the matlab community but the question is more general.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to compare your subsection matrix `B` with every possible subsection matrix of the reference matrix `A` (so that it has the same size, as a matrix `B`) and find the most similar piece.

By comparison, I mean the estimation of the difference, e.g. if `B_i` is some subsection of matrix A, you can calculate:

```
 d_i=sum(sum(sum((B_i-B).^2)));
```

After that, you need to find the minimum of $d_i$. If you are working with big matrices A(NxNxN) and B(MxMxM), there are `(N-M)^3` possible submatrices `B_i` with the same size as matrix `B`. The algorithm will be quite expensive.

However, there is an alternative implementation using convolutions. You can take a look at the [Particle Image Velocimetry](https://www.mech.kth.se/~olle/pivkurs/Intro_to_PIV.pdf) algorithm, that is really similar to your problem.